# Is QNX® Momentics IDE for BlackBerry® 10 Native SDK Version: 10.0.4 providing Drag and drop functionality in Blackberry 10 native SDK development?

Tags: qnx, blackberry-10

I have a good experience with BlackBerry Java Development Environment. I need to know about QNX based IDE for development of Blackberry 10. I successfully installed and ran a small example.

But here I am not finding any drag and drop IDE. I expected that it contain that type of editor, but unfortunately I am not able to find this feature. I am using following IDE:

QNX® Momentics IDE for BlackBerry® 10 Native SDK

Version: 10.0.4

Also the IDE is not showing all hints. How to get Hints?

Is it required manually include header files?

Please help me where can I find this feature in this IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i got following answer from Blackberry adviser

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Visual-Drag-and-Drop-Editor-for-Cascades/m-p/1759935#M300

This is currently not available. Please consult the BB NDK documentation for information and updates:

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/

https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just to let you know, drag and drop is now available in Momentics (version 10.0.9). You can drag UI components into your code window and it will auto populate the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If there is error on your qml file that will show it on right square corner so you can come to know that something is wrong on qml. for adding header file and all it not gives any hint like eclips android and eclipse bb is give to users. You have to manually find which header file is missing and add that.